# Change to a virtual network

Tags: networking, linux-networking

We have a setup of two computers. S is the server with internet access and C is the client that is connected to the server via the 192.168.0.0/24 network. This works just fine, but a third computer, C2, should be connected to C.

The problem is that C and C2 must connect via 192.168.0.0/24 and C2 must not see S. Thus, we want to add a virtual network between S and C that uses 192.168.1.0/24.

I.e., we have:

```
S <-- 192.168.0.0/24 -- C <---- X ---- C2
```

And we want:

```
S <-- 192.168.1.0/24 -- C <-- 192.168.0.0/24 -- C2
```

We add the following to /etc/network/interfaces in S (previously connected to C via eth0), and executes "ifup eth0.1":

```
auto eth0.1
iface eth0.1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.254
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

And in C, after "ifdown eth0", remove the old if and type:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Then, "ifup eth0".

And it doesn't work! Ping just says:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.2
PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.254 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.254 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

When we change back everything works and we can even ping eth0.1 from the client. How do you change network from the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you used a VLAN 802.1q interface, it's not an alias interface, so you have 2 different VLAN,and you need a typical router-on-sitck configuration to do this or you need to create a dummy interface with dummy module (may be it's more easy) in this way:

```
#! /bin/bash
modprobe dummy
ip link set name ethvirt dev dummy0
ifconfig ethvirt hw ether 00:22:22:03:02:74
ifconfig ethvirt 192.168.1.254 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! Should I write this on the client (C) side?

Comment: No this configuration it's ok if you have one server with just one interface, I suppose that's the problem.
Otherwise you need to perform a VLAN configuration on your switch or remove eth0.1 in eth0